# Calling an Input in onPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

I am trying to call my emailInput and have it show up on my createPassword page, specifically where youremail@email.com is. I have given the two pages below, the email page consisting of a user input and the password page where I want that user input to appear on. I cannot really wrap my head around how to refer to the Input in my onPress. Any insight at all is appreciated more than you know!

Also, can I call two onPress's like that? Or do I need to create two functions and do it that way?

SignUpEmail.js

```
export default class SignUpEmailPage extends Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#A2A2A2'};}
  
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        
        {/* Email Input */}
      <Container style = {styles.emailInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel >
            <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Email Address</Label>
                <Input
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}               
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
                />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Container>


<View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <ContinueButton
       
      onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('CreatePassword', { emailInput:  })}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreatePassword')}
      /> 
      </View>
```

CreatePassword.js

```
export default class CreatePasswordPage extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#A2A2A2'};}
  
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
       
         {/* Password Input */}
      <Container style = {styles.passwordInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel>
           <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Password</Label>
              <Input
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}
                
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
         
              />
         </Item>
       </Form>
      </Container>

        <View style={styles.containerHeader}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Create a Password</Text>
        </View>
        
      <View style={styles.containerCaption}>   
        <Text style={styles.caption}> Lets create your Password for 
 
        </Text> 
      </View>
      <View style={styles.containerCaption2}>   
        <Text style={styles.caption}> youremail@email.com</Text> 
      </View>

      

      <View style= {styles.backArrowPlacement}>
      <BackArrow 
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpEmail')} 
      />
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <ContinueButton
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PhoneVerification')} 
      /> 
      </View>
    </View>

    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `navigation.navigate` as it needs Hooks implementation in the functional component. You can do is

```
export default class SignUpEmailPage extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            color1: '#A2A2A2',
            inputValue: '', // add state here
        };
    }

    updateInputValue = (evt) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: evt.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <Input 
             value = {this.state.inputValue}
              onChange={this.updateInputValue }
            />           
            <ContinueButton
               //onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('CreatePassword', { emailInput:  })} // remove this
               onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreatePassword',{ emailInput: this.state.inputValue })} // use this like
            />

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay cool, thankyou. Another problem I having is how to call the input, what would I put after emailInput:

Comment: After `emailInput` you have to add it's value like `emailInput: inputValue` which you get from the input container

Comment: I understand you have to add the input value there but what would that be in my case? I cant figure it out, inputValue gives me an error so I am assuming thats not correct

Comment: I marked it as correct! Thank you for your time, this is big for me! If you have the time and do not mind explaining how the evt.target.value works? Also if you could explain how to print the inputValue, I tried  <Text}>{this.setState.inputValue}</Text> along with some others but thats my best bet.

Comment: Again, I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Glad it works for you :-) You get access to the field value by using the `event.target.value` syntax and for more details you can read here https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_forms.asp